# Compile error when trying to print an integer in Rust v0.13.0

Tags: compiler-errors, rust

I thought this would work:

```
let x = 5;
println!("x = {}", x);
```

But it gives the following compile error:

```
main.rs:3:24: 3:25 error: unable to infer enough type information to locate the impl of the trait `core::fmt::Show` for the type `_`; type annotations required                                                                             
main.rs:3     println!("x = {}", x);
```

Am I missing something?

I'm using an [online Rust compiler](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_rust_online.php) and the version they have is `Rust v0.13.0`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The error is because the compiler you use is old. For this compiler, try by explicitly giving an integer type:

```rust
let x: i32 = 5;
println!("x = {}", x);
```

On newer compilers, your code will work as is, even without specifying `i32` explicitly:

```
let x = 5;
println!("x = {}", x);
```

You can use the official online compiler at https://play.rust-lang.org/, which is always an up-to-date version of Rust.